# Unknown string format: DD/MM/YYYY - HH:MM:SS

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time-series

I am trying to convert my Date columns of my DataFrame to `datetime[ns]` which is in the format `"%d/%m%Y - %H:%M:%S"`. I have tried multiple methods like, `pd.to_datetime`, `datetime.strptime`, `datetime.strftime`, etc. But every time its showing the error:

TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
.
.
.
.
.
Unknown string format: DD/MM/YYYY - HH:MM:SS.

```
        Date                Var1    Var2
0   19/03/2021 - 00:01:00   22.52   0
1   19/03/2021 - 00:16:00   22.93   0
2   19/03/2021 - 00:31:00   22.79   0
3   19/03/2021 - 00:46:00   22.65   0
4   19/03/2021 - 01:01:00   22.34   0
```

above is the sample of my DataFrame.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is `print (df['Date'].head().tolist())` ?

Comment: ['19/03/2021 - 00:01:00', '19/03/2021 - 00:16:00', '19/03/2021 - 00:31:00', '19/03/2021 - 00:46:00', '19/03/2021 - 01:01:00']

Comment: `datetime` has no format, it's a binary value. You can't change its format because it doesn't have one. What you posted is text data. Where does the data come from? What are the *actual* types? What does `df.dtypes` return? Are you trying to "parse" what's already a datetime? Or should be? Excel for example already supports binary dates, and Pandas can load these date values as `datetime`. For CSV files, `read_csv` can parse and read dates in various formats

Answer (score 1):

#### for given specific example...

It is typo, you need `/`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['19/03/2021 - 00:01:00', 
                           '19/03/2021 - 00:16:00', '19/03/2021 - 00:31:00', 
                           '19/03/2021 - 00:46:00', '19/03/2021 - 01:01:00']})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S")
                                                    ^^^
print (df)
                 Date
0 2021-03-19 00:01:00
1 2021-03-19 00:16:00
2 2021-03-19 00:31:00
3 2021-03-19 00:46:00
4 2021-03-19 01:01:00
```

---

#### in general...

Tell the computer ***exactly*** what to do by selecting from [strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). All components of date and time have to be matched by a **directive** `%...` while all other characters have to be exactly as in the input. The computer cannot ***guess*** that you meant a `.` to be a `/` for example:

```
s = "10.14.1986"
dt = datetime.strptime(s, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

will fail with

> ValueError: time data '10.14.1986' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y'

because I used the wrong delimiter, `/` should be `.`

Comment: I tried to copy the format from the error and put it in the code:                                                      'df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date, format = '%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S')' but again it is showing error: time data 'DD/MM/YYYY - HH:MM:SS' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S' (match)

Comment: @sambehera the error tells that ` 'DD/MM/YYYY - HH:MM:SS'` is PART OF the input data, a value in the dataframe, how could you have that ? That is obviously not a date, that is letters. Because the code given here works nice

Comment: @sambehera - What return `df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format="%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S", errors='coerce').isna(), 'Date'].tolist()` ?

Comment: Yes, I got the problem and now it is solved. Thank you very much for your suggestions. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: @jezrael why did you set the post to Community ownership ? :(